# C++ map::find or map::iterator which is more efficient w.r.t complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary

As we know map::find returns an iterator pointing to location where it find the location of the key. Also as its a binary search operation the complexity is O(logn). So it seems internally it maintain an iterator and that will be return on success. 
So which one is more efficient find or iterator as I think both will provide the same complexity at run time (I may be incorrect).
So can you please suggest where to use find and where to use iterator. As in one of the implementation I need to look into map for a particular keys (as it can contain N keys out of which we are interested in m keys only). So whether find will be more efficient or iterator.
Also what will be good way to handle find failure case as I don't want to put much if else case in code which will increase the complexity.

Comment: Iterator is just an interface wrapper over pure pointers, find is function that returns iterator. What the point of comparison two different meanings?

Comment: Actually I am not comparing iterator with find. I am looking for a more efficient way to look for a key value pair in a Map. As Map can have N unknown keys but I will be looking only for M knows keys. So was thinking whether to use find or iterator as we know what to look for in a map.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean but using `std::map<...>::find()` will be more efficient than than using `std::lower_bound()` on map's iterators: the binary search on the internal tree just navigates the tree and has `O(log(n))` performance with `n` being the size of the map. `std::lower_bound()` would also do a binary search but it would need to use `operator++()` and/or `operator--()` to move the iterator. Thus, it would have `O(n)` performance. I think it shouldn't even compile but I'm not entirely sure whether it doesn't compile.

Comment: It will compile; `std::lower_bound` only requires a forward iterator (since it uses `std::distance` to compute differences between iterators).  But you are right that it will be slower since `std::distance` on a non-random-access iterator is linear time.

Comment: std::lowe_bound is not linear for std::map, it's logarithmic!
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html

Comment: @lampat:the most often executed operation determines the complexity. It does `O(log(n))` comparisons but on non-random-access iterator it does `O(n)` iterator operations. See the documentation, e.g., [http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html) and [http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html).

Comment: @iampat: `std::map<>::lower_bound` is logarithmic however ;)

Answer (score 1):

For a start they do two different things. Secondly it depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb: if you can choose between a generic algorithm (`std::find` here) and a container specific algorithm of the same name (`std::map<...>::find` here), then use the container specific one.

Nobody would have bothered implementing a container specific one if it were not more efficient than the generic version, it would have been a loss of time.